# What is this structure and how to use it?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get into some python code and I found this:

```
nodesList.append(
    Node.Node(
       NodeInfo.NodeInfo(
          nodeID,
          nodeStructure["text"].encode('utf8'),
          nodeStructure["type"],
          None,
          schemeValue,
          schemeIDValue
       ), adjEdges
    )
)
```

I can't tell if it's a list or an array.. or what!

The thing is *I don't know how to access adjEdges* .

I've been able to access NodeInfo with `(currentNode.nodeInfo).text`, for example, but `currentNode.ajdEdges` doesn't work :/

EDIT 2: Seems I was utterly unready to ask this question x( But thanks to everyone who's helping because I was getting nowhere and now I see a light at the end of the tunnel ^^;

**Node.py**

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, nodeInfo, edges):
        self.nodeInfo= nodeInfo
        self.edges= edges

    def __str__(self):
        outputString= "Show Node:" + '\n' + "--- NodeInfo:" + '\n' + str(self.nodeInfo) + '\n' + "--- Edges" + '\n'

        for e in self.edges:
            outputString= outputString + str(e) + '\n'

        return outputString + '\n'
```

**Edge.py**

```
class Edge:

    def __init__(self, edgeInfo, destinationNodeId):
        self.edgeInfo= edgeInfo
        self.destinationNodeId= destinationNodeId

    def getEdgeInfo(self):
        return self.edgeInfo

    def getDestinationNodeId(self):
        return self.destinationNodeId

    def __str__(self):
        return "Edge:" + '\n' + "--- EdgeInfo \n" + str(self.edgeInfo) + '\n' + "--- DestinationNodeId" + '\n' + "   " + str(self.destinationNodeId) + '\n'
```

Do you know what's going on?

Comment: Do you have access to the Node class? Is this from some module? If yes what is it?

Comment: We don't know how to access it either, because you have not shown the code for the Node or NodeInfo classes. What does Node's `__init__` do with that parameter? Once you know that, you'll know how to access it. (But note that `adjEdges` is being passed to Node, not NodeInfo.)

Comment: Oh I thought this would be enough! I'm gonna search for those classes

Comment: And what does `Node` look like? Because `adjEdges` is used as the second argument in the `Node` instantiation. Comments asked for the `Node` class, but you've now given the definitions of two other classes.

Comment: You've added `EdgeInfo` and `NodeInfo`, but `Node` is the one with `adjEdges`, it's the one we need to see

Comment: Use `currentNode.edges`. You can see it for yourself directly in the code for `Node`.

Comment: I just added `Node` and `Edge`, sorry everyone :/

Comment: "Seems I was utterly unready to ask this question": you'll want a [rubber ducky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) ;-).

Comment: Yeah seems kinda obvious to me too, now... Thank you everyone x( @9769953, since you were quicker, do you want to leave an answer? ps: haha, I didn't know this rubber ducking thing! Good tip :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the value of `adjEdges` passed to `Node` with `currentNode.edges`.